# Аналог пагинации через OFFSET ... LIMIT

Tags: sql

Почитал статью про оптимизацию запросов, где расписано, что при стандартном подходе пагинации через `OFFSET ... LIMIT` идет сканирование всей таблицы, что замедляет отработку запроса. В этой же статье предложено использовать вместо этого следующий запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id > 10 LIMIT 10
```

Вместо

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

Но тогда как мне узнать какой отступ делать? То-есть такой способ подходит, когда первичные ключи идут последовательно и все на месте. Но если у нас отсутствуют некоторые записи или `id` идут непоочередно, как тогда узнать с какого `id` начинать выборку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пагинация — вопрос сложныи и во многом
зависящий от задачи, нагрузки, и, конечно, конкретной
СУБД. Возьмите, например,
[эту](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/03/30/five-ways-to-paginate/)
статью о *PostgreSQL*. Описываются пять (!)
различных способов, и каждый со своими недостатками.

В вашем случае вы можете сортировать по любому параметру,
даже если есть «дырки», но при этом вы потеряете
возможность переместиться на *N*'ую
страницу. То есть, при отображении у вас будет
только кнопка «Дальше», которая ведёт на страницу,
где производится что-то типа:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id > $last_id_on_page LIMIT 10;
```